# Macros multicolumn and row in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I have a table like this but in LaTeX when I use `\multicolumn` or `\multirow` the output view is not perfect and it seems that there is some overlapping between cells and when we use these commands there is not any separator between cells. Can you help me to make this table better.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1.2cm} | p{1.6cm} | p{1.6cm} | p{1.6cm} | p{1.6cm} |}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Scenario} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Urban} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Highway} \\
     & Without RSU & With RSU & Without RSU & With RSU \\ \hline
    PDR & e-HBCWC & HBCWC & e-HBCWC & \\ \hline
    End-to-End Delay & e-HBCWC & DCF & HBCWC & \\ \hline
    Overall & e-HBCWC & e-HBCWC & e-HBCWC & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: In line 1 of your table is the last `&` missing ...  Can you please complete your code snippet to a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've still to see a table using `\multirow` that can't be improved by removing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt} % adjust to fit
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Urban} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Highway} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
Scenario         & Without RSU & With RSU & Without RSU & With RSU \\
\midrule
PDR              & e-HBCWC     & HBCWC    & e-HBCWC     & \\
End-to-End Delay & e-HBCWC     & DCF      & HBCWC       & \\
Overall          & e-HBCWC     & e-HBCWC  & e-HBCWC     & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to use `\multirow` and ruled tables (which are evil), try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newlength{\without}
\newcommand{\adjustsize}[1]{\makebox[\without]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\settowidth{\without}{Without RSU}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt} % adjust to fit
\begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{l|} }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Scenario} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Urban} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Highway} \\
& Without RSU & \adjustsize{With RSU} & Without RSU & \adjustsize{With RSU} \\ \hline
    PDR & e-HBCWC & HBCWC & e-HBCWC & \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}End-to-End\\ Delay\end{tabular}
      & e-HBCWC & DCF & HBCWC & \\ \hline
    Overall & e-HBCWC & e-HBCWC & e-HBCWC & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The adjustments to `\tabcolsep` are done in order to make the table fit. You may need it or not, depending on your document's text width.